# Write a SQL query to determine which users have more than 10 unread messages

Tags: mysql, sql

Table **users** have columns:

```
user_id,
username,
email,
friend_count
```

Table **messages** have columns:

```
message_id, 
from_user_id, 
to_user_id, 
date_sent, 
date_read, 
message
```

when date_read=NULL (we know that this is an unread msg)

Now I want to return the users (probably username) and the no of unread messages. I wrote the query below:

QUERY:

```
SELECT u.username, unread_msgs
FROM messages AS m
INNER JOIN users AS u ON m.to_user_id=u.user_id
WHERE unread_msgs = COUNT(date_read=”NULL’);
```

I know the count function is wrong because no subquery allowed in aggregate functions, can someone tell me what other way can i get the result that i want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So where is the `unread_msgs` column?

Comment: Dont use `”` and `’` quotes, use a text editor to code not a word processor so you get plain ascii quotes. Oh and if you start a string literal with a double quote you have to finish it with a double quote

Comment: *determine which users have more than 10 unread messages* ```... GROUP BY user_id HAVING SUM(date_read IS NULL) > 10```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter for messages where `date_read` is `NULL` and `GROUP BY` `username`.

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(*) AS unread_msgs
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users u ON m.to_user_id = u.user_id
WHERE date_read IS NULL
GROUP BY u.username
```

Alternatively, if you also want to see users who do not have unread messages.

```
SELECT u.username, SUM(CASE WHEN date_read IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unread_msgs
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users u ON m.to_user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.username
```

Comment: Still you are not including the most important case `which users have more than 10 unread messages`

Comment: @ErgestBasha It was in his title, but he made no mention of it in his post and no attempt in his query. If it's a real requirement it can be accommodated easily with a `HAVING`.

Comment: CASE usage is excess in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.username, count(m.message_id) as unread_msgs
FROM messages AS m
INNER JOIN users AS u ON m.to_user_id=u.user_id
WHERE m.date_read IS NULL
group by u.username
HAVING unread_msgs > 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  u.user_id,u.username,unread_m.unread_count from
(
  select to_user_id,count(message_id)unread_count
  from messages
  where date_read is null
  group by to_user_id
  having count(message_id)>10
)unread_m
join users as u on unread_m.to_user_id=u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this might be what youre looking for:

```
SELECT u.username, unread_msgs
FROM messages AS m
INNER JOIN users AS u ON m.to_user_id=u.user_id
WHERE unread_msgs = (select count(*) where date_read is null)
```

Im a bit confused about what you want to do tho

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated query to show the users who haven't read their messages. Also, [`null`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html) is a special value and can't use comparison like `=`.

```
select username,
       (select count(*) from messages b where b.to_user_id = a.user_id and date_read is null) unread_messages
from users a
```